# ggplot2 custom legend shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, legend, scatter-plot

When we have both shape and color legend in scatter plot, the shape of color legend is misleading:

```
foo <- data.frame(
  length=runif(10),
  height=runif(10),
  group=as.factor(sample(3,10,rep=T)),
  quality=as.factor(sample(2,10,rep=T))
)

ggplot(foo, aes(x = length, y = height, color=group, shape=quality)) + 
  geom_point(size=5)
```

This will produce the plot below. As you see, the "circle" shape is reserved for the objects of `quality==1`, however in the `group` legend, all 3 groups are presented in "circle" shapes - with different colors, this can be misleading.

It was too much better if the `group` legend was represented by a shape not already reserved for a specific purpose, like just to fill the whole legend item with the specific color.

Do you have any simple idea how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is possible to manually change the properties of the legend using `guides`:

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x = length, y = height, color=group, shape=quality)) + 
  geom_point(size=5) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15)))
```

Just play around with the `shape` paramater to find an appropriate shape.

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to change the black color of the shapes legend?

Comment: @Ali This, of course, is similar to the technique in the answer: Add `+ guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = "pink")))` to the plot.