# Custom legend shape and size ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I tried to customize the legend to and I want to fill the legend with appointed colors I want and delete any slash or symbol inside.

```
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      axis.title.y.right = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, size = 10, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      plot.background=element_blank(),
      legend.position="left",
      legend.title=element_blank(),
      legend.text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
      legend.key = element_rect(fill = c("red", "blue")))
```

[image]

However, I though I still need to add something to fulfill my desire.
`legend.key` seems incorrect here.
What I want is: oh! but the first is red rather than orange.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I find is to use guides function. Indeed, the following code does the work :

```
df <- data.frame(value = rnorm(100), group = as.factor(sample(c(1, 2), size = 100, replace = T)))

ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y=value, col = group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "red", "2" = "blue")) +
  geom_point() + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 10))) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y.right = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, size = 10, vjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank(),
        legend.position="left",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background =  element_blank())
```

My insipiration is several other post on stackoverflow :

[ggplot2 custom legend shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456765/ggplot2-custom-legend-shapes)

[How to increase the size of points in legend of ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415963/how-to-increase-the-size-of-points-in-legend-of-ggplot2)